Database Error in model .. Couldn't initialize file system for path
Recently the following error ocurs when running DBT on Azure Databricks:
Database Error in model un_company_sat (models/2_un/partner/sats/un_company_sat.sql)
Couldn't initialize file system for path abfss://dp-ext-fab@stcssdpextfabprd.dfs.core.windows.net/__unitystorage/catalogs/64552de9-4ff0-4c5f-b4a7-0aef0d6c821a/tables/1bd27775-ca51-435a-8c1a-1042391ac471/part-00000-8121312f-d7a0-4a5b-964a-4c2f4ea4f2ec-c000.snappy.parquet
Has anybody an idea how to fix this error or how to further analyze it?

the Error is related to ADLS filesystem can you share how are you connecting ADLS using ADB?

The error occured becase this table is a shallow clone from another table.
The original table was re-created.
To fix this we dropped the table and made another shallow clone.
